# How to get the values of two foreign key columns when they correspond to the same key?

Tags: sql

I need help in SQL , regarding this database https://www.kaggle.com/hugomathien/soccer.
I need an SQL statement that gives a table of the home team name and the away team name for a random game ( I chose Match.match_api_id = 492476)
If i run this :

```
SELECT Team.team_long_name , Match.home_team_api_id
FROM Team JOIN Match
ON Match.away_team_api_id = Team.team_api_id 
WHERE Match.match_api_id = 492476;
```

I get the away team name , but not the home team name (instead I get the value of Match.home_team_api_id , as expected).
If I run :

```
SELECT Team.team_long_name , Match.away_team_api_id
FROM Team JOIN Match
ON Match.home_team_api_id = Team.team_api_id 
WHERE Match.match_api_id = 492476;
```

I get the home team name , but not the away team name (instead I get the value of Match.away_team_api_id , as expected).
The problem is that both of the foreign keys Match.home_team_api_id and Match.away_team_api_id corespond to : Team.team_api_id , so when I get one I "lose" the other.

Is there an SQL statement to get both the home team name and the away team name of random match in the same table?

Comment: I've removed the tag spam here. Tag spam doesn't help us help you; it makes it harder to. Tagging multiple conflicting tags means that we have no idea what technology you are really asking about, making your question unclear and difficult to answer. It can also easily end up attracting downvotes and close votes if they make the question unclear. Just tag the technologies you are actually asking about. [Edit] your question and tag correctly, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if the selection criteria is solely about the `Match` table, it should be the first table you mention.

Second, you're allowed to use `JOIN` (or `INNER JOIN` as it's more often written) more than once.

```
SELECT T1.team_long_name as Away_team_long_name,
       T2.team_long_name as Home_team_long_name
FROM Match
   INNER JOIN Team as T1
      ON Match.away_team_api_id = T1.team_api_id 
   INNER JOIN Team as T2
      ON Match.home_team_api_id = T2.team_api_id
WHERE Match.match_api_id = 492476;
```

Rephrasing this as a human procedure:

1. Use the `match_api_id` to look up the `Match` row in the `Match` table.
2. Take the `away_team_api_id` from the `Match` row and use it to look up a Team in the `Team` table. Report the `team_long_name` of that Team as the Away team long name.
3. Take the `home_team_api_id` from the `Match` row and use it to look up a Team in the `Team` table. Report the `team_long_name` of that Team as the Home team long name.

Comment: Why we are taking TEAM as self join can't we take MATCH table?

Comment: You're asking for two team names about a single match, right? Then you need one match row and two team rows.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider Accepting this question -- i.e., marking it as the correct Answer -- by using the green checkmark. Also consider waiting up to 24 hours to see if someone answers it better than I did.

Comment: also, "self join" isn't in play here. A self join would be like `FROM Match INNER JOIN Match as M2 ON Match.something=M2.somethingelse`

Answer (score 0):

You can join the `Team` table twice, once for the away team and once for the home team. The aliases for the tables help track which is which. Something like:

```
SELECT 
 hometeam.team_long_name homename,
 Match.home_team_api_id, 
 awayteam.team_long_name awayname, 
 Match.away_team_api_id
FROM Match INNER JOIN Team hometeam
  ON Match.home_team_api_id = hometeam.team_api_id
 INNER JOIN Team awayteam
  ON Match.away_team_api_id = awayteam.team_api_id 
WHERE Match.match_api_id = 492476
```