# How can I connect two tables in SQL depending on the data?

Tags: sql, date, select, datatable, content-values

It's quite simple problem but I am begginer and i have problems with it.

I have 2 tables in database

1. matches id, team1id, team2id, score, date
2. teams id, name

If I want to select team1 name, team2 name, score and date what command should I use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the values of two foreign key columns when they correspond to the same key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72277175/how-to-get-the-values-of-two-foreign-key-columns-when-they-correspond-to-the-sam)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a double "join" on teams table. I wrote a sheet of how you should use it :

```
select 
     matches.id,
     teamA.name,
     teamB.name,
     score,
     date 
from matches
inner join teams teamA
on teamA.id = matches.team1id
inner join teams teamB 
on teamB.id = matches.team2id
```

Comment: If it helps you, note my response as answer. Next time, try to do some research by your own, there are tons of tutorial about that case.